# Bayesian Changepoint Detection

Tags: r, bayesian

I am trying to run a Gibbs sampler in R with 4 chains for two changepoints. As mentioned in the link below:
https://medium.com/@anggerpamungkas/change-point-detection-1b2e588fe6b0

[image]

```
library(boot)# Coal disaster data
data(coal)
x <- 1851:1962
y <- tabulate(floor(coal[[1]]))
y <- y[x] # disaster counts per year

# Prior parameters -------------------------------------------------------------
a_prior <- 2
b_prior <- 1

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
n_iter <- 40000 # number of iterations
n_chains <- 4 # number of chains

gibbs_sampler_two_changepoints <- function(y, n_iter, n_chains, a_prior, b_prior) {
  n <- length(y)
  all_samples <- vector("list", n_chains) # Store samples for all chains
  
  for (chain in 1:n_chains) {
    # Initial values for the rate parameters and the change points
    lambda <- rgamma(3, shape = a_prior, rate = b_prior)
    tau <- sort(sample(2:(n-2), 2)) # Ensure tau1 < tau2
    
    chain_samples <- matrix(0, nrow = n_iter, ncol = 5) # Store lambda1, lambda2, lambda3, tau1, tau2
    
    for (i in 1:n_iter) {
      # Update lambda1
      a_post <- a_prior + sum(y[1:tau[1]])
      b_post <- b_prior + tau[1]
      lambda[1] <- rgamma(1, shape = a_post, rate = b_post)
      
      # Update lambda2
      a_post <- a_prior + sum(y[(tau[1]+1):tau[2]])
      b_post <- b_prior + (tau[2] - tau[1])
      lambda[2] <- rgamma(1, shape = a_post, rate = b_post)
      
      # Update lambda3
      a_post <- a_prior + sum(y[(tau[2]+1):n])
      b_post <- b_prior + (n - tau[2])
      lambda[3] <- rgamma(1, shape = a_post, rate = b_post)
      
      # Update tau1
      tau1_probs <- sapply(1:(tau[2]-1), function(t) {
        sum(dpois(y[1:t], lambda[1], log = TRUE)) + sum(dpois(y[(t+1):tau[2]], lambda[2], log = TRUE))
      })
      tau[1] <- sample(1:(tau[2]-1), 1, prob = exp(tau1_probs - max(tau1_probs)))
      
      # Update tau2
      tau2_probs <- sapply((tau[1]+1):(n-1), function(t) {
        sum(dpois(y[(tau[1]+1):t], lambda[2], log = TRUE)) + sum(dpois(y[(t+1):n], lambda[3], log = TRUE))
      })
      tau[2] <- sample((tau[1]+1):(n-1), 1, prob = exp(tau2_probs - max(tau2_probs)))
      
      # Store the samples
      chain_samples[i, ] <- c(lambda, tau)
    }
    
    all_samples[[chain]] <- chain_samples
  }
  
  return(all_samples)
}

# Run the sampler 
all_chains_samples <- gibbs_sampler_two_changepoints(y, n_iter, n_chains, a_prior, b_prior)

## 2 chhangepoint prediction ---------------------------------------------------
# Function to simulate cumulative disasters
simulate_disasters <- function(params, data) {
  lambda1 <- params[1]
  lambda2 <- params[2]
  lambda3 <- params[3]
  T1 <- params[4]
  T2 <- params[5]
  
  # Simulate the number of disasters for each period
  c(rpois(T1 - 1, lambda1), 
    rpois(T2 - T1, lambda2), 
    rpois(length(data) - T2 + 1, lambda3)) |> cumsum()
}

cumulative_disasters <- cumsum(y)

combined_samples <- do.call(rbind, all_chains_samples)

# Simulate disasters for each sample
simulated <- t(apply(combined_samples, 1, function(params) simulate_disasters(params, y)))

# Calculate median and prediction intervals
sim_median <- apply(simulated, 2, median)
sim_lower <- apply(simulated, 2, quantile, probs = 0.025)
sim_upper <- apply(simulated, 2, quantile, probs = 0.975)

# Find the most probable changepoints (MAP of T1 and T2)
map_T1 <- as.integer(names(sort(table(combined_samples[, 4]), decreasing = TRUE)[1]))
map_T2 <- as.integer(names(sort(table(combined_samples[, 5]), decreasing = TRUE)[1]))

# Create the plot
ggplot(data = data.frame(Year = x, Cumulative = cumulative_disasters), aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = sim_lower, ymax = sim_upper), fill = "green", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = sim_median), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Cumulative), color = "black") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = x[map_T1], color = "blue", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = x[map_T2], color = "blue", linetype = "dashed") +
  annotate("text", x = x[map_T1], y = min(cumulative_disasters), label = paste("MAP(T1) =", x[map_T1]), hjust = 0, vjust = 0, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", x = x[map_T2], y = min(cumulative_disasters), label = paste("MAP(T2) =", x[map_T2]), hjust = 1, vjust = 0, size = 3) +
  labs(title = "2 Changepoints - Prediction", y = "Cumulative Number of Disasters", x = "Year") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Although after my simulation I do get different changepoint years for MAP T1 and MAPT2. I was wondering what could i be doing wrong here. My samples seems to be converged.

This is the plot from the medium article:
[image]

and this is the plot I have generated:

[image]

Comment: So your change points are off by 1 year? Have you tried re-running everything with a different seed? Gibbs is inherently stochastic so you might get slightly different answers every time you run it.

Comment: If you need further reassurance, look at the *distribution* of the estimates of your changepoints, not just the point estimates.  I suspect the variance will be relatively large...